# Can't get Compute Engine instances list

Tags: virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I'm testing out Compute Engine and am hitting a snag. I've set up a project (jwl-project-1) and created an instance (instance-1). After authenticating with gcloud auth login, I set the project like this:

```
gcloud config set project jwl-project-1
```

And then tried to get a list of instances:

```
gcloud compute instances list
```

In return, I get this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.list) Some requests did not succeed:
- Invalid value for project: jwl-project-1
```

I basically accepted the default values for project and instances (micro-disk). What am I missing?

Answer (score 8):

As the error indicates there is no project called 'jwl-project-1' under your account. Try to use your Project ID instead:

$ gcloud config set project `<project-id>`

Answer (score 3):

You can see all of your projects on the [Google Cloud Platform Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/). Use the name under the *Project ID* heading, **not** the *Project Name* heading.

The *Project ID* is a unique identifier which cannot be changed after project creation and is used everywhere to identify the project, whereas the *Project Name* is a human-readable name which can be changed after project creation.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you authenticate using oauth2 and a browser:
'gcloud auth login'
Paste the link to the browser, complete the authentication and then check by 
'gcloud compute instances list '